# Makefile wildcard with multiple file extensions

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I process all files of a given extension.

I'm simplyfying this in the real world it makes more sense as I know "what I need to do" ;-)

The following works:

```
MY_FILES = $(wildcard *.ex1)
BASENAMES = $(basename $(MY_FILES))

.PHONY: run
run : $(MY_FILES)
    for name in $(BASENAMES); do\
        # do what I need to do
    done

.PHONY: clean
clean :
    # clean up the mess
```

Now what I would like to do is process not just *.ex1 but also a dozen or so others (but all files in the very same way, so no differentiation by file type in "do what I need to do"). The file extensions do not follow any pattern. So, what is the most convenient way to code that multiple file extension wildcard case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the dozen of files are always the same then you can hardcode them like this

```
MY_FILES = $(wildcard *.ex1)
MY_FILES += filename.foo
MY_FILES += filename.bar
```

or if just the extension is always the same then like this

```
MY_FILES = $(wildcard *.ex1)
MY_FILES += $(wildcard *.foo)
MY_FILES += $(wildcard *.bar)
```

see here for more information: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Appending.html#Appending

if they are not always the same then you have to make them follow *some* pattern. for example to have them all in some directory

```
MY_FILES = $(wildcard somedir/*)
```

Comment: No they are not. 100 of *.ex1 this time, 66 of *.ex2 next time or any mix of the lot.

Comment: Ah you edited this, thanks the second case will be good enough if there is no easier way that ommits the dozen extra lines. It would work. I didn't realize you could concatenate or maybe rather merge the results like that

Comment: You could also write: `MY_FILES = $(wildcard *.ex1 *.foo *.bar)` if you wanted to put everything in one line.

Comment: that works but seems to be undocumented https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions